# Junction Table with mutiple primary keys

Tags: atk4

I started to learn Atk just a week ago and I decided to reimplement the business intranet which is becoming unmaintainable.

The model abstraction is very cool to use but I wonder how to specify multiple primary keys for my junction tables.

For example, I have sites and I want to assign machines on them for a period.
[Junction table](http://sluggogle.free.fr/junctionTable.png)

This is very important to me to not touch the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can do that using `joins` in your Models if you're not allowed to add simple auto_incremented `id` field in that junction table.

But adding `id` field will be much more easier for you and also will work better in future.

For example, you can have some issues with deleting record without unique id field. I know (id_machine,id_site) is most likely unique in your case, but it's still hard to work with. One simple id field is easier, faster and better :)

Comment: Thx I guess I will try to redefine the database on my side then migrate data if convincing. Once done, do I have to link models with `joins` or using `hasMany` ?

Comment: Then with hasMany & hasOne.

Answer (score 0):

Dark has a good suggestion. You can also create a calculated ID field, I have never tried it myself but do try it

```
$model->getElement('id')->destroy();
$model->addExpression('id')->set('contact(id_machine,"-",id_site)');
```